# Scale out PhantomJs instances on Azure in .Net

Tags: c#, azure, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJs like http server.
I have only one instance and every request is performed sequentially.
I would to scale out PhantomJs http server instances using Windows Azure with .Net framework (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

You can host your own ASP.net application that uses preccess.start for phantomjs
this will create phantomjs instance for each request, and its managed by IIS

```
 System.Diagnostics;
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        Arguments = "your.js plus any arguments here",
        FileName = "path/to/phantomjs.exe"
    };

    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = processStartInfo,
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    //pipe the output
    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => {
        //args.Data has output from phantomjs
    };


        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit(20000);
        process.CancelOutputRead();
```

As you know this solution will not work on Azurewebsites because GDI+ is disabled on Azurewebsites right now.

Comment: Thanks Ammaroff , I read this issue in other post. I saw a solution with java ( highchart site)  but It's not  very scale out solution , It's only pooling process management. In the cloud It's more complicate to manage :S. Thanks again !